# Mesopotamia laws 196, 197 and 198

Tags: law, mesopotamia

While doing some research I stumbled upon some old Mesopotamian laws. Reading through them I found a series of conflicting laws. They state

> 196: If a man put out the eye of another man, his eye shall be put out.
>
> 197: If he break another man’s bone, his bone shall be broken.
>
> 198: If he put out the eye of a freed man, or break the bone of a freed man, he shall pay one gold mina.

The first two laws do not conflict with each other. Yet the third one makes the whole thing a mess.

Did law 198 state that they also had to pay 1 mina if they break bones or eyes (and have theirs broken), or did it mean if they pay 1 mina they did not have their bones broken, or eyes taken out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking at a poor translation: There were [three classes of individuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_law#Three_classes) under the law. A *mushkenu* was a landless *freed man* who had to accept monetary compensation for corporal injuries done to him. He often owed a type of feudal duty to a landholder or patron.

Answer (score -2):

I look at it as 196~197 speak of as if a slave owner breaks the bone of another mans slave~ that slave would not be able to perform all his duties so you have the right to break the bone of one of his slaves.
I look at 198 as a freed man meaning a free man working for some sort of pay, he was able to adjust his work with a broken bone ~ hence pay while he was learning to adjust until he was able to sustain himself again.

Comment: This answer would benefit from sources. Does it add anything not already documented in Mr. Geerkens' answer?

Comment: I just tried to put it in more of a laymans terms